# Piping information from text box

Tags: powershell

I have a script that requires input from the user in a textbox. Once the user hits enter or clicks OK the data in the textbox must be transferred to a command. Here is the textbox portion of the code. I am just a couple months in to PS. Feel free to criticize :)

```
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form;
    $objForm.Text = "Enter Patch Number";
    $objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,100); 
    $objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen";
    $InputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $InputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,50)  
    $InputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20) 
    $Form.Controls.Add($InputBox) 
    $Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
    $Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,30) 
    $Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110,80) 
    $Button.Text = "Send to Patch Command" 
    $Button.Add_Click({$version}) 
    $Form.Controls.Add($Button) 
    $wks=$InputBox.text
    .\anp deploypatch -patch=$version
    $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
    [void] $Form.ShowDialog()
```

This is the command that must have the user input piped to the end. An example of this cmd being executed correctly is...
    .\anp deploypatch -patch=**437.1237**

In other words, the user types in the item in bold above and hits enter and the command is executed based on the version the user inputs. Main thing I want here is how to xfer the users input in to my desired command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code. In your original code `$form` does not exist, the control position were random, and the enter key was not linked to the button.

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form;
$objForm.Text = "Enter Patch Number";
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,200); 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen";
$InputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$InputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,20)  
$InputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20) 
$objForm.Controls.Add($InputBox) 
$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(50,50) 
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110,80) 
$Button.Text = "Send to Patch Command"
$Button.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()}) 
$objForm.AcceptButton = $Button # the button is linked to the enter key
$objForm.Controls.Add($Button) 
$wks=$InputBox.text
$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
$version = $InputBox.Text
#$version
.\anp deploypatch -patch=$version
```

Answer (score 0):

The below seems to do the trick let me know how you get on.

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form;
$Form.Text = "Enter Patch Number";
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,200); 
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen";

$InputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$InputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,50)  
$InputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$InputBox.text = ""  
$Form.Controls.Add($InputBox) 



$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,30) 
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110,80) 
$Button.Text = "Send to Patch Command" 
$Button.Add_Click({patch}) 
$Form.Controls.Add($Button) 

Function patch {
$wks=$InputBox.text
Invoke-Expression "\anp deploypatch -patch='$wks'"
}

$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
[void] $Form.ShowDialog()
```